# Using python and ArcPy to read multiple files, apply a function and write into new a directry

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I haven't used python yet; I want to read multiple GeoTiff files and resample them based on another single file, and be able to write all the files in a new directory. I can use R raster package to that, but it takes a long time. Here is what I do in R and I want to be able to do the exact process in Python using ArcPy module.

```
    setwd("path to directory")
    files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="tif", all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE) 
    s <- stack(files)
    resamp <- raster("new_raster.tif")
    s2 <- resample(s, resamp,method='bilinear')
    s3 <- unstack(s2)
    setwd("new_directory)
    for(i in seq_along(s3)){writeRaster(s3[[i]], file=outputnames[i],format="GTiff", options=c("INTERLEAVE=BAND","COMPRESS=NONE"))}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This process involves creating a list of your rasters and instantiating a for loop to resample each raster in your list.

A python script using arcpy methods would look SOMETHING like this:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = <rasterDirectory>
outDir = <output directory>
RstList = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIFF")
xResult= arcpy.GetRasterProperties(<in_rst>, "CELLSIZEX")
yResult= arcpy.GetRasterProperties(<in_rst>, "CELLSIZEY")
x = xResult.getOutput(0)
y = yResult.getOutput(0)
for Rst in RstList:

       arcpy.Resample_management(Rst, outDir+arcpy.Describe(Rst).name, x y, "BILINEAR")
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know how I can read in that single file (`resamp` in the example')? I want to use that instead of the `<cell size>` to make sure the resampling process changes the dimension as well.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  You can use arcpy. GetRasterProperties_management(in_raster, <property type>) .  Set a variable (ex. cellSzX) equal to this method and another variable to get the result object (cellSzX.getOutput(0)) and plug it into the resample method.  Here is the resource link.  http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m7000000   You may need to pass two variables into <cell size>, CELLSIZEX and CELLSIZEY.

Comment: I updated my initial answer to include what I think may work.  Let me know how it pans out.  You can even pass the path of the input raster into the <cell size> argument rather than use GetRasterProperties. This would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: I think I should you clip and resample, cause I want to change the dimensions and the cell size.

Comment: pass a single number into the cell size parameter to specify the square cell size, whatever you want.  arcpy.Clip_management(Rst) can be added to the loop (before resample) if you want to clip all rasters in your list, this of course will create another output so just be sure to keep your file names in check.  Arcpy is very well documented in the online arcgis resources if you need more instruction on how to use any of the arcpy methods.

Comment: Also @DNM, Please accept my answer if it effectively answered your initial question.  I'd appreciate it as I just started building my stack profile today!  Thanks.